# Without using DISTINCT, how to group data without altering value?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a feeling this is a dumb question with a simple answer, but here goes.

How can I group the following data without using `DISTINCT`? `@Table` has 5 rows, which shows data for Hrs 5-9. I just don't like `DISTINCT`.

Since I need to display all hours of the day upto Hr9 (including 0-4), I'm joining it with table `DimTime`. `DimTime` has all hours, but with its 15-min intervals. So, `DimTime` looks like this:

```
Hour    Minute
0       0
0       15
0       30
0       45
1       0
1       15
1       30
1       45
```

So here's my script:

```
declare @table table
(
    Hour int,
    Value int
)

insert into @table select 5, 25
insert into @table select 6, 34
insert into @table select 7, 54
insert into @table select 8, 65
insert into @table select 9, 11

select d.hour, t.hour, sum(value) 
from @table t 
left join dimtime d on d.hour = t.hour
group by d.hour, t.hour
```

If I use `GROUP BY`, then I need to have an aggregate function. So if I use `SUM`, it'll multiply all values by 4. If I remove the aggregate function, I'll get a syntax error.

Also, I cannot use a `CTE` since the contents in @table comes from a `CTE` (I just didn't include it here).

Here's the result that I need to display:

```
Hour    Value
0       null
1       null
2       null
3       null
4       null
5       25
6       34
7       54
8       65
9       11
```

Comment: Show us sample data and desire result. Right now isnt clear what you try to get.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: I have included sample data and the tsql script.. The only thing missing is the exact data to be returned, but I assumed that could be inferred from the text in the question.

Comment: well you assumed wrong, I dont sure what result you want. Also not sure what mean  `I need to display all hours of the day upto Hr9 (including 0-4)`

Comment: Apparently I did, so I've added it. And changed from `inner join` to `left join`.

Comment: Yes a `left join` should solve your problem. But your sample should be bigger, because not sure if you need `SUM()`  or not

Comment: As to "I just don't like DISTINCT": `DISTINCT` is not per se bad, but it's often a sign of poorly written queries. As a database is usually normalized, it is rarely necessary to remove duplicates from your results - as long as you didn't just produce these duplicates yourself with the same thoughtlessly written query :-)

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a condition `WHERE minute = 0` to return only one row per hour.

Answer (score 1):

If you really with to skip the sorting operation on `dimtime` with the use of `distinct` clause then check the below explanation.

---

Display all hours (0-9) from `dimtime` and sum the `value` given in `@table` for a particular hour:

```
SELECT
  d.hour, SUM(t.value)
FROM
  dimtime d
  LEFT JOIN @table t
    ON d.hour = t.hour
WHERE d.minute = 0 -- retrieves one row for every hour from dimtime
GROUP BY d.hour
ORDER BY d.hour -- not needed, but will give you resultset sorted by hour
```

Assuming that you have a row with value `minute = 0` in your `dimtable` for every hour you could just limit the rows retrieved for join operation. That will work with any value from list `0, 15, 30, 45`.

`SUM()` will work properly by summing all the values for a given `hour` in `@table`. If there are no rows with a particular hour, it will return `0` value.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should have a better reason for not using a programming function than "I just don't like it"
2. You can have a CTE that uses another CTE

@dnoeth provided an excellent answer, but here's another option:

```
SELECT
    d.hour,
    t.value
FROM
    @table t
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT hour FROM dimTime) d ON d.hour = t.hour
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT *
FROM DimTime D
LEFT JOIN myTable T
       ON D.Hour = T.Hour
WHERE D.Minute = 0
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a0d07/4)**

**Output**

```
| Hour | Minute |   Hour |  Value |
|------|--------|--------|--------|
|    0 |      0 | (null) | (null) |
|    1 |      0 | (null) | (null) |
|    2 |      0 | (null) | (null) |
|    3 |      0 | (null) | (null) |
|    4 |      0 | (null) | (null) |
|    5 |      0 |      5 |     25 |
|    6 |      0 |      6 |     34 |
|    7 |      0 |      7 |     54 |
|    8 |      0 |      8 |     65 |
|    9 |      0 |      9 |     11 |
```

Answer (score -1):

> If I use GROUP BY, then I need to have an aggregate function

Only if you include expressions in your `SELECT` that are not part of your group key.  You could certainly do

```
select d.hour, t.hour, value 
from @table t
inner join dimtime d
  on d.hour = t.hour
group by d.hour, t.hour, value
```

or

```
select d.hour, t.hour, MIN(value) 
from @table t
inner join dimtime d
  on d.hour = t.hour
group by d.hour, t.hour
```

Note that the first query gives you the exact same results as `DISTINCT` (and may even be compiled to the same query plan) so I'm not sure what your aversion is to `DISTINCT`.

Comment: When I first started working with tsql many years ago, I remember that I used DISTINCT on very large results to eliminate duplicates. And I remember that the DB took a big hit for using that keyword instead of grouping. So I guess it just stayed with me.

Comment: But you're right, there's no reason to avoid using `DISTINCT`.